# Plural of a mathematical variable

Tags: plural-forms, mathematics

How should I write the plural of a mathematical variable? E.g., in these sentences:

1. The values of f(u<sub>i</sub>|u<sub>j</sub>) are independent for different [u<sub>j</sub>/u<sub>j</sub>s/u<sub>j</sub>'s].
2. The values of f(u<sub>i</sub>|u<sub>j</sub>) are independent for different [j/js/j's].

Comment: From my experience, you usually do not need to make variables themselves plural; for example, you would say "... are independent for different values of u" etc.

Comment: @BittersweetNostalgia -- Your comment would make a good answer.

Answer (score 1):

> How should I write the plural of a mathematical variable? E.g., in these sentences:
>
> - The values of f(ui|uj) are independent for different [uj/ujs/uj's].
> - The values of f(ui|uj) are independent for different [j/js/j's].

[image: MathJax]
Source: [How to refer to plural of mathematical symbols - with or without an apostrophe [closed]](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/192173/how-to-refer-to-plural-of-mathematical-symbols-with-or-without-an-apostrophe).

See also: [Apostrophes and plural forms](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/punctuation/apostrophe).

Comment: It would be good to put a summary of the links in your answer.

Comment: @Shayan - That is already done . That **is** what sources and references are.

Comment: I mean something that doesn't require the reader to go to another webpage such that the reader reads my question and reads your answer to it, with the links as supplementary material.

Comment: That already is what is there, people can already do that. --- Step 1: Read, Step 2: Understand, Step 3: Doubt, Step 4: Check the sources and references, Step: 5 Don't linger or revisit just move along. --- There's no additional requirements, simply do things normally.